# Need to call server side event using __doPostBack

Tags: javascript, asp.net, rad-controls

I have server side event like this.

```
protected void RadTreeView1_ContextMenuItemClick(object sender, RadTreeViewContextMenuEventArgs e)
    {
         // implementation here.
    }
```

I am trying to call it from client side javascript. I have tried __doPostBack("contextMenuItemID", "some string")

it posts the page back to server, but this does not invoke the  original ContextMenuItemClick event. How can I invoke the original contextMenuItemClick event with proper event Args?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll want to look at using the [ClientScriptManager.GetPostBackEventReference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.getpostbackeventreference.aspx) method. This will create the correct javascript call ("__doPostBack") for the control/action using the ClientScriptManager (*untested example*):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function callPostBack() {
        <%= Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(RadTreeView1, String.Empty) %>;
    }
</script>
```